# Вывести слова на python

Tags: python

Дано предложение, в котором слова разделены одним пробелом(начальных и конечных пробелов нет). Получить и вывести на экран все его слова. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Что у вас не получилось при попытке самостоятельно написать такой элементарный скриптик?

Comment: Поищите описание функции print. Её достаточно.

Comment: Смотря как именно нужно вывести.

Comment: @GrAnd Ну, судя по уровню сложности вопроса ответ очевиден "Как угодно" :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
astring='This is a sample'
alist=astring.split(' ') #преобразуем строку в список. пробел как разделитель
for it in alist:
 print(it)
```

Answer (score 1):

Получил и вывел все слова

```
predlozhenie ="this is sparta"
print(predlozhenie)
```

Comment: не те уже спартанцы D